# How to post a tweet when a new file is uploaded onto a directory over FTP

Tags: twitter, ftp

I really hope this is the correct platform for my question. I have spent countless hours on Google but I came up empty-handed.

How can I automatically post a tweet when a new file is uploaded onto a FTP directory? I have tried integromat.com but it doesn't really work.

Your input is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That completely depends on how your FTP server works.

Comment: If you are not developing an FTP server, but merely using an existing FTP software, then this is not the correct site to ask. Please move the question to [su] or [sf]. And when-reposting there, include details about your FTP server. Unless you want to develop a program or script that monitors the FTP server (remotely) or a program or script that runs on the server and monitors a local folder ("local" for the FTP server) for changes. In general, your question is way too broad for any SE site.